# Firebase polymer two way binding : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__firebaseKey__' of undefined

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a collection of objects in a firebase db

```
<template>
    <firebase-collection
      location="https://incandescent-inferno-8405.firebaseio.com/objects/-JubQT-WrBaVlSeuKJhO"
      data="{{object}}"
    </firebase-collection>

    <paper-input value="{{object.attribute::input}}"></paper-input>
</template>
```

When I start typing in the input field I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__firebaseKey__' of undefined
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. Does your console show any errors after your browser finishes loading? If so, what are they? Can you show a screen shot? 2. What is this `<firebase-collection>` element? Is that an element you are building? Or is that one you are importing? If importing, can you please provide the github link to the repository? 3. What `<script>` code are you using in this element? Can you show us all the code please? It would be easier to troubleshoot if we know what all the code for your custom element looks like. Because what you think might be irrelevant might be very relevant.

Comment: 1. No 2. I imported it https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/ 3. There is no javascript involved, this should work with HTML only

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using a firebase-document element instead of firebase-collection.